# Type inference failed using contains method with JSONArray in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, contains, iterable

I have a simple iteration through a JSONArray where I try to find a string value inside of the MutableList <'String'>? filteredLocations:

```
for ((index, feature) in features.withIndex()) {
val userIds = feature.getProperty("userIds").asJsonArray
    for(userIdOfLocation in userIds) {
        if (userIdOfLocation in filteredLocations) {
            features.removeAt(index)
        }
    }
}
```

However, the compiler raises this issue when trying to use "in":

> Type inference failed: The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly

I am not sure how I have to specify it explicitly here?

Edit: I have simplified the code a little, it looks like this now:

```
private fun filterMarkerLocations(markers: MutableList<Feature>, id: String): Feature? {
    for (marker in markers) {
        val assignedUserIds = marker.getProperty("userIds").asJsonArray
        if(id in assignedUserIds) {
            println("hit")
            println(marker)
            println(id)
            return marker
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Still the same issue.

Comment: Do you use old or new type inference?

Comment: To reproduce the issue, add the complete code.

Comment: I don't know if I use old or new type, where can I see that? @vanyochek

Comment: Also, it's generally not a good idea to modify a collection while iterating through it (unless you're doing both through the same iterator object).  You might get a ConcurrentModificationException, or strange behaviour.

Comment: @gidds yes, you are right, I got this issue, but I changed the code now in a way that I do not need to modify original collection anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable new type inference - you should add compiler argument 
`"-XXLanguage:+NewInference"`

Groovy Gradle DSL:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-XXLanguage:+NewInference"]
    }
}
```

Kotlin Gradle DSL:

```
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class)
        .forEach {
            it.kotlinOptions { freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-XXLanguage:+NewInference") }
        }
```